# Inserting 'continue' statement within a function to be called later in another functions 'For loop' statement

Tags: javascript, for-loop, google-apps-script

To simplify my code, I have made a function that contains an 'if' statement. The function is meant to be called within a 'For' loop in another function. I want to put a 'continue' statement inside the custom function to be called later. Is there any possible way to do this without error? Code is written in Google Apps Script.

```js
function example1() {
  //code here
  continue;
  }
}
        
function example2() { 
  for(var x = 1 ; x <= 2 ; x++) {
  example1();
  }
}
```

I get an error for calling the 'continue' statement within the example1() function because the 'continue' statement is not in a 'For' loop. But the example1() function is only created to be called within the example2() 'For' loop statement.

Comment: On Google Apps Script "custom function" usually refers to Google Sheets user defined functions. Ref. https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope, you have to directly `continue` inside of the `for` loop. You could make your function return a boolean then perform a `continue` as needed.

```
function example1() {
  return shouldLoopContinue; // Add your own logic here
}

function example2() {
  for (var x = 1; x <= 2; x++) {
    if (example1()) {
      continue;
    }

    doSomeOtherWork();
  }
}
```